# Automatically assign a value to name attribute in hyperref

Tags: pdftex, xetex, hyperref, forms

Look at the text box I create with `hyperref`. I have documents with over 600 text fields, some of which are constantly changing. Is there any way in `hperref` to automatically assign the names of the text fields?

```
\begin{table}[!h]
        \tymin=50pt
        \tymax=\textwidth
        \caption{ASUS Rog Rampage VI Extreme Encore - Erklärung der Rückseitenanschlüsse}
        \begin{tabulary}{18cm}{|L|L|L|} 
            \hline
                Nr  &   Bezeichnung &   Erklärung\\\hline
                %\parbox[POS][HÖHE][POS-INNEN]{BREITE}{INHALT}
                1   &   \makecell[l]{\parbox[0pt][1cm][t]{7cm}{\TextField[name=field1,width=6cm,height=1cm,multiline=true, bordercolor=black]{}}}   & \makecell[l]{\parbox[0pt][1cm][t]{10cm}{\TextField[name=field2,width=9cm,height=1cm,multiline=true, bordercolor=black]{}}}\\ \hline
                2   &   \makecell[l]{\parbox[0pt][1cm][t]{7cm}{\TextField[name=field3,width=6cm,height=1cm,multiline=true, bordercolor=black]{}}}   & \makecell[l]{\parbox[0pt][1cm][t]{10cm}{\TextField[name=field4,width=9cm,height=1cm,multiline=true, bordercolor=black]{}}}\\ \hline   
                3   &   \makecell[l]{\parbox[0pt][1cm][t]{7cm}{\TextField[name=field5,width=6cm,height=1cm,multiline=true, bordercolor=black]{}}}   & \makecell[l]{\parbox[0pt][1cm][t]{10cm}{\TextField[name=field6,width=9cm,height=1cm,multiline=true, bordercolor=black]{}}}\\ \hline   
                4   &   \makecell[l]{\parbox[0pt][1cm][t]{7cm}{\TextField[name=field7,width=6cm,height=1cm,multiline=true, bordercolor=black]{}}}   & \makecell[l]{\parbox[0pt][1cm][t]{10cm}{\TextField[name=field8,width=9cm,height=1cm,multiline=true, bordercolor=black]{}}}\\ \hline   
                5   &   \makecell[l]{\parbox[0pt][1cm][t]{7cm}{\TextField[name=field9,width=6cm,height=1cm,multiline=true, bordercolor=black]{}}}   & \makecell[l]{\parbox[0pt][1cm][t]{10cm}{\TextField[name=field10,width=9cm,height=1cm,multiline=true, bordercolor=black]{}}}\\ \hline      
                6   &   \makecell[l]{\parbox[0pt][1cm][t]{7cm}{\TextField[name=field11,width=6cm,height=1cm,multiline=true, bordercolor=black]{}}}  & \makecell[l]{\parbox[0pt][1cm][t]{10cm}{\TextField[name=field12,width=9cm,height=1cm,multiline=true, bordercolor=black]{}}}\\ \hline
                7   &   \makecell[l]{\parbox[0pt][1cm][t]{7cm}{\TextField[name=field13,width=6cm,height=1cm,multiline=true, bordercolor=black]{}}}  & \makecell[l]{\parbox[0pt][1cm][t]{10cm}{\TextField[name=field14,width=9cm,height=1cm,multiline=true, bordercolor=black]{}}}\\ \hline  
                8   &   \makecell[l]{\parbox[0pt][1cm][t]{7cm}{\TextField[name=field15,width=6cm,height=1cm,multiline=true, bordercolor=black]{}}}  & \makecell[l]{\parbox[0pt][1cm][t]{10cm}{\TextField[name=field16,width=9cm,height=1cm,multiline=true, bordercolor=black]{}}}\\ \hline  
                9   &   \makecell[l]{\parbox[0pt][1cm][t]{7cm}{\TextField[name=field17,width=6cm,height=1cm,multiline=true, bordercolor=black]{}}}  & \makecell[l]{\parbox[0pt][1cm][t]{10cm}{\TextField[name=field18,width=9cm,height=1cm,multiline=true, bordercolor=black]{}}}\\ \hline  
                10  &   \makecell[l]{\parbox[0pt][1cm][t]{7cm}{\TextField[name=field19,width=6cm,height=1cm,multiline=true, bordercolor=black]{}}}  & \makecell[l]{\parbox[0pt][1cm][t]{10cm}{\TextField[name=field20,width=9cm,height=1cm,multiline=true, bordercolor=black]{}}}\\ \hline
                11  &   \makecell[l]{\parbox[0pt][1cm][t]{7cm}{\TextField[name=field21,width=6cm,height=1cm,multiline=true, bordercolor=black]{}}}  & \makecell[l]{\parbox[0pt][1cm][t]{10cm}{\TextField[name=field22,width=9cm,height=1cm,multiline=true, bordercolor=black]{}}}\\ \hline
                12  &   \makecell[l]{\parbox[0pt][1cm][t]{7cm}{\TextField[name=field23,width=6cm,height=1cm,multiline=true, bordercolor=black]{}}}  & \makecell[l]{\parbox[0pt][1cm][t]{10cm}{\TextField[name=field24,width=9cm,height=1cm,multiline=true, bordercolor=black]{}}}\\ \hline
                13  &   \makecell[l]{\parbox[0pt][1cm][t]{7cm}{\TextField[name=field25,width=6cm,height=1cm,multiline=true, bordercolor=black]{}}}  & \makecell[l]{\parbox[0pt][1cm][t]{10cm}{\TextField[name=field26,width=9cm,height=1cm,multiline=true, bordercolor=black]{}}}\\ \hline  
        \end{tabulary}
    \end{table}
```

Comment: make a complete *and* small example. There is no need to show 26 fields (which would have to be changed to show a solution).

Answer (score 0):

I would define a custom macro that takes an integer as argument and outputs one full table row consisting of a row number and the necessary fields with the appropriate names. If you combine this with a counter, you don't even need to input the number every time.

In the following example, I defined a new counter `tablrownum` that initially is set to 1. The value of this counter is taken as argument to the macro `\tablrow` if no explicit argument is provided. On each call of `\tablrow`, the counter is increased by one. If an explicit argument is provided, the counter is set to the value of this argument (and increased by one).

Note that you need to reset the counter to 1 inside the `tabluary` environment because `tabulary` will run the contents of the environment several times which would increase the counter every time.

The fields are automatically named `nameX` and `descX` where `X` is the number of the table row (or the number explicitly stated using the optional argument of `\tablrow`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.25cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{tablrownum}
\newcommand{\tablrow}[1][\thetablrownum]{
  #1 &   
  \makecell[l]{\parbox[0pt][1cm][t]{7cm}{\TextField[name=name#1,width=6cm,height=1cm,multiline=true, bordercolor=black]{}}} & 
  \makecell[l]{\parbox[0pt][1cm][t]{10cm}{\TextField[name=desc#1,width=9cm,height=1cm,multiline=true, bordercolor=black]{}}} 
  \ifnum#1=\thetablrownum\stepcounter{tablrownum}\else\setcounter{tablrownum}{\numexpr#1+1\relax}\fi
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[!h]
        \tymin=50pt
        \tymax=\textwidth
        \caption{ASUS Rog Rampage VI Extreme Encore -- Erklärung der Rückseitenanschlüsse}
        \begin{tabulary}{18cm}{|L|L|L|} 
            \hline\setcounter{tablrownum}{1}
            Nr & Bezeichnung & Erklärung \\ \hline
            \tablrow \\ \hline 
            \tablrow \\ \hline
            \tablrow \\ \hline
            \tablrow \\ \hline
            \tablrow \\ \hline
            \tablrow[20] \\ \hline
            \tablrow \\ \hline
        \end{tabulary}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Question: How does your command  \tablrow know to start with 1?

Comment: At the beginning of the `tabulary`, I placed `\setcounter{tablrownum}{1}` which sets the counter `tablrownum` to 1. The value of this counter is taken as argument to `\tablrow` if you don't provide an explicit argument. On each call of `\tablrow`, the counter `tablrownum` is increased by one. If you provide an explicit argument to `\tablrow`, the counter `tablrownum` is set to this explicit value (and increased by one).

Comment: Thank you very much. The example works well and has sparked my interest in macros. Unfortunately, I don't understand one part of your solution. What exactly is the purpose of [\thetablrownum] in the macro header. Are you defining an environment varaible here?

Comment: No. If you define a counter, like I did with `\newcounter{tablrownum}`, then you can access the current value of this counter using `\the<counter name>`. Hence, `\thetablrownum` returns the current value of the counter `tablrownum`. The macro definition `\newcommand{\tablrow}[1][\thetablrownum]{...}` means: Create a new macro with the name `\tablrow` that takes one (`[1]`) optional argument which should take the value of `\thetablrownum` per default (if it is not explicitly given).

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can you recommend a book or internet source where you can read about this?

Comment: Maybe have a look at this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/47927

Comment: Good link, quite long. @ZJ, you can also have a read here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Macros . // It's good practice to place a comment `% ` immediately at the end of each macro-line to avoid spurious spaces in "print". // To find examples here, you might use https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macros and add more keywords to the search field. // BTW, `\def ` was used in TeX, and should be `\newcommand ` in LaTeX.